# Autofac: Rerouting Service Resolutions

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

How do I re-route service resolutions with Autofac?

In other words: How do I divert resolutions to first check with a Common Service Locator before checking its own registrations?

The solution must work with both external resolutions (i.e. via Resolve) and internal resolutions (i.e. those used for auto-wiring of dependencies).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I am attempting to create a Common Service Registry. This framework will essentially aggregate potentially multiple containers as one and expose them as a CSL. The containers therefore need to consider the existence of other containers (i.e. the aggregate CSL). This is the CSL which I would like to re-route resolutions too.

Comment: This question doesn't really make much sense to me, maybe you should add some more around what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree with Chris: The CSL is as abstraction over frameworks such as Autofac, so in that case it doesn't make sense to first call CSL (which redirects to Autofac) and if it fails call Autofac directly. So what is it you are trying to accomplish, and why do you think you need the CSL anyway. Unless you have a reusable framework, you shouldn't use the CSL (or the Service Locator pattern in general), and even for reusable frameworks it is arguable.

Comment: I am attempting to create a Common Service Registry. This framework will essentially aggregate potentially multiple containers as one and expose them as a CSL. The containers therefore need to consider the existence of other containers (i.e. the aggregate CSL). This is the CSL which I would like to re-route resolutions too.